# Using list tail in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

This is the first time I've used list-tail in scheme and I'm having problems with the output. I have a very simple procedure which is

```
(define(printlist n numbers)
(list-tail (list)n))
 (printlist 2'(5 3 3 5 5))
```

I'm trying to print out the last 2 numbers in the list. I'm getting an error but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've looked at several examples online but can't find solution.

Comment: `list` is a procedure. When you do `(list 'a)` you create a list with one element `a`. `(list)` returns the empty list `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [documentation for list-tail](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-tail%29%29):

```
(define (last-n-elements n lst)
  (list-tail lst (- (length lst) n)))

(last-n-elements 2 `(5 3 3 5 5))
```

It takes 2 parameters: the list and the the number of elements to skip.
So, if you want last `n` elements of a list, you skip over `length(list) - n` characters.

Comment: Im thinking what I need to do to take the first three numbers of the list. Would list-ref be appropriate to do that?

Comment: [list-ref](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-ref%29%29) returns the element at a given index, so it could assist you in building your own `list-head` function.